# How to sort the documents based on nested element ( when unwind is applied in multiple fields ) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the documents similar to below. What i need here is that I need to sort the documents based on "**date**" field in **to/cc/bcc** as per the user (**email_id**). The user email_id might present in anyone or more than one section (**to/cc/bcc**). Wherever user email exist, in that particular **date** field should be used to sort the documents. Tried with $unwind on **to,cc,bcc** and  applied **$match, $sort**, it did not work properly. In simple terms, apply **unwind** on more than one fields and **sort** the document based on **date** field on selected user. Thank in advance.

```
[
  {
    _id: "60642127b982sa55299q674444a",
    subject: "Email 1",
    body: "Body 1",
    to: [
      {
        email_id: "test1@gmail.com",
        name: "test 1",
        date: "2021-10-01 12:00:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test2@gmail.com",
        name: "test 2",
        date: "2021-10-01 13:00:00"
      }
    ],
    cc: [
      {
        email_id: "test3@gmail.com",
        name: "test 3",
        date: "2021-10-01 14:00:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test4@gmail.com",
        name: "test 4",
        date: "2021-10-01 15:00:00"
      }
    ],
    bcc: [
      {
        email_id: "test5@gmail.com",
        name: "test 5",
        date: "2021-10-01 16:00:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test6@gmail.com",
        name: "test 6",
        date: "2021-10-01 17:00:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test2@gmail.com",
        name: "test 2",
        date: "2021-10-01 13:00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "60642127b982sa55299q674444b",
    subject: "Email 2",
    body: "Body 2",
    to: [
      {
        email_id: "test1@gmail.com",
        name: "test 1",
        date: "2021-10-01 12:10:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test2@gmail.com",
        name: "test 2",
        date: "2021-10-01 13:10:00"
      }
    ],
    cc: [
      {
        email_id: "test3@gmail.com",
        name: "test 3",
        date: "2021-10-01 14:10:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test4@gmail.com",
        name: "test 4",
        date: "2021-10-01 15:10:00"
      }
    ],
    bcc: [
      {
        email_id: "test5@gmail.com",
        name: "test 5",
        date: "2021-10-01 16:10:00"
      },
      {
        email_id: "test6@gmail.com",
        name: "test 6",
        date: "2021-10-01 17:10:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "to.email_id": "test2@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "cc.email_id": "test2@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "bcc.email_id": "test2@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      subject: 1,
      body: 1,
      concat: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$to",
          "$cc",
          "$bcc"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$concat"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "concat.email_id": "test2@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      uniqueValues: {
        $addToSet: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$uniqueValues"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "uniqueValues.concat.date": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SY3pe13mvrm)

Comment: when we use this query we have duplicate documents, do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide test data that can fully present your problem.

Comment: We had tested with documents (updated in the question). In some cases, the same user might be there in more than one sections (to/cc/bcc), that's where we got this issue. As we added the test2@gmail.com in to&bcc sections leads to this issue

Comment: I update my answer by using `$group` and `$addToSet` to avoid duplicate documents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when we apply the sorting along with grouping, we do not  get the same set of results always right as it is getting shuffled every time when we run the query. But we need to sort the data in correct order.

Comment: update... add `$unwind` and move `$sort` to the buttom